# Back-transform binomial and betabinomial to counts with emmeans

Tags: r, lsmeans, glmmtmb

My first outcome is a bounded count (range = 0-5, not zero-inflated, not overdispersed), so I specified a model using a successes-failures matrix and a binomial distribution:

```
library(emmeans)
library(glmmTMB)

mod1 <- glmmTMB(cbind(out1, 5-out1) ~ 1 + poly(SurveyYr, 2) + coVar1 + coVar2 +
  (1 + poly(SurveyYr, 2)| orgId),
  family=binomial, data=modelDf)
```

I've already figured out how to back-transform from logit to probabilities:

```
refGrd1 <- ref_grid(mod1, at=list(SurveyYr = 0:2))
emmeans(refGrd1, "SurveyYr", weights="cells", type="response")

 SurveyYr  prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
        0 0.835 0.0193 Inf     0.794     0.870
        1 0.740 0.0253 Inf     0.687     0.786
        2 0.784 0.0235 Inf     0.734     0.827

Results are averaged over the levels of: coVar1
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale
```

That still doesn't get me back to my 0-5 count range, so I tried this:

```
refGrd2 <- ref_grid(mod1, at=list(SurveyYr = 0:2),
  tran=make.tran(type="scale", y=modelDf$out1)
emmeans(refGrd2, "SurveyYr", weights="cells", type="response")

 SurveyYr prob    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
        0 5.91 0.239 Inf      5.44      6.38
        1 4.92 0.223 Inf      4.48      5.36
        2 5.34 0.237 Inf      4.87      5.80

Results are averaged over the levels of: coVar1
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the scale(3.14, 1.7) scale
```

The `prob` values are a tad high compared to the observed and go beyond the count limit of 5, but they do fit the observed pattern with the dip in the middle. I'm not sure my assumption about the `make.tran` call matches with how `glmmTMB` actually handles the successes-failures matrix and link function for the binomial distribution. I hate to be the person who asks "Did I get that right?" but... did I get that right? I haven't seen anything else posted about this issue.

I tried the same thing with another bounded count outcome with the same range, but which was zero-inflated and overdispersed, so I fit that one with a betabinomial distribution. (The distribution handled the zero-inflation and overdispersion on its own, so I didn't have to add those to the model specification.)

```
mod2 <- glmmTMB(cbind(out2, 5-out2) ~ 1 + poly(SurveyYr, 2) + coVar1 + coVar2 +
  (1 + poly(SurveyYr, 2)| orgId),
  family=betabinomial, data=modelDf)

refGrd3 <- ref_grid(mod2, at=list(SurveyYr = 0:2),
  tran=make.tran(type="scale", y=modelDf$out2)
emmeans(refGrd3, "SurveyYr", weights="cells", type="response")

 SurveyYr  prob    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
        0 1.074 0.232 Inf     0.619      1.53
        1 0.617 0.230 Inf     0.166      1.07
        2 1.209 0.244 Inf     0.731      1.69

Results are averaged over the levels of: coVar1 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the scale(1.65, 2) scale
```

Those are actually pretty darn close to the observed means. It almost seems a little too easy which makes me wary... At any rate, if this is right, this might be a good resource for folks, as I don't see this documented anywhere else.